# Project structure for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I started an application in Google App Engine right when it came out, to play with the technology and work on a pet project that I had been thinking about for a long time but never gotten around to starting.  The result is [BowlSK](http://www.bowlsk.com).  However, as it has grown, and features have been added, it has gotten really difficult to keep things organized - mainly due to the fact that this is my first python project, and I didn't know anything about it until I started working.

What I have:

- Main Level contains:

  - all .py files (didn't know how to make packages work)
  - all .html templates for main level pages
- Subdirectories:

  - separate folders for css, images, js, etc.
  - folders that hold .html templates for subdirecty-type urls

Example:
http://www.bowlsk.com/ maps to HomePage (default package), template at "index.html"
http://www.bowlsk.com/games/view-series.html?series=7130 maps to ViewSeriesPage (again, default package), template at "games/view-series.html"

It's nasty.  How do I restructure?  I had 2 ideas:

- Main Folder containing: appdef, indexes, main.py?

  - Subfolder for code.  Does this have to be my first package?
  - Subfolder for templates.  Folder heirarchy would match package heirarchy
  - Individual subfolders for css, images, js, etc.
- Main Folder containing appdef, indexes, main.py?

  - Subfolder for code + templates.  This way I have the handler class right next to the template, because in this stage, I'm adding lots of features, so modifications to one mean modifications to the other.  Again, do I have to have this folder name be the first package name for my classes?  I'd like the folder to be "src", but I don't want my classes to be "src.WhateverPage"

Is there a best practice?  With Django 1.0 on the horizon, is there something I can do now to improve my ability to integrate with it when it becomes the official GAE templating engine?  I would simply start trying these things, and seeing which seems better, but pyDev's refactoring support doesn't seem to handle package moves very well, so it will likely be a non-trivial task to get all of this working again.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First, I would suggest you have a look at "[Rapid Development with Python, Django, and Google App Engine](http://sites.google.com/site/io/rapid-development-with-python-django-and-google-app-engine)"

GvR describes a general/standard project layout on page 10 of his [slide presentation](http://sites.google.com/site/io/rapid-development-with-python-django-and-google-app-engine/rapid_development_with_django_gae.pdf?attredirects=0).

Here I'll post a slightly modified version of the layout/structure from that page. I pretty much follow this pattern myself. You also mentioned you had trouble with packages. Just make sure each of your sub folders has an __init__.py file. It's ok if its empty.

### Boilerplate files

- These hardly vary between projects
- app.yaml: direct all non-static requests to main.py
- main.py: initialize app and send it all requests

### Project lay-out

- static/*: static files; served directly by App Engine
- myapp/*.py: app-specific python code

  - views.py, models.py, tests.py, __init__.py, and more
- templates/*.html: templates (or myapp/templates/*.html)

Here are some code examples that may help as well:

### main.py

```
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from myapp.views import *

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', IndexHandler),
  ('/foo', FooHandler)
], debug=True)

def main():
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

### myapp/views.py

```
import os
import datetime
import logging
import time

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from models import *

class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    date = "foo"
    # Do some processing        
    template_values = {'data': data }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../templates/', 'main.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class FooHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    #logging.debug("start of handler")
```

### myapp/models.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class SampleModel(db.Model):
```

I think this layout works great for new and relatively small to medium projects. For larger projects I would suggest breaking up the views and models to have their own sub-folders with something like:

### Project lay-out

- static/: static files; served directly by App Engine

  - js/*.js
  - images/*.gif|png|jpg
  - css/*.css
- myapp/: app structure

  - models/*.py
  - views/*.py
  - tests/*.py
  - templates/*.html: templates

Comment: Once you get to 20 or 30 views, and a couple "views" that just handle posts and then redirect, do you break them out into separate files?  Perhaps in myapp/views/view1.py, myapp/views/view2.py?  Or that just my Java/C# background showing through?

Comment: I edited my post to address larger projects. I hope that helps. Keep in mind that in some cases it will be a judgement call.

Comment: I have a similar layout, but use "app" instead of "myapp".

Comment: Could someone provide a working example for such a project layout? I haven't found anything suitable.

Answer (score 17):

My usual layout looks something like this:

- app.yaml
- index.yaml
- request.py - contains the basic WSGI app
- lib

  - `__init__.py` - common functionality, including a request handler base class
- controllers - contains all the handlers. request.yaml imports these.
- templates

  - all the django templates, used by the controllers
- model

  - all the datastore model classes
- static

  - static files (css, images, etc). Mapped to /static by app.yaml

I can provide examples of what my app.yaml, request.py, lib/**init**.py, and sample controllers look like, if this isn't clear.

Comment: Hi Nick, please do it! I need to compare between different solutions as well :) Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I would like to see some examples too if that's possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I implemented a google app engine boilerplate today and checked it on github. This is along the lines described by Nick Johnson above (who used to work for Google).

Follow this link [gae-boilerplate](https://github.com/droot/gae-boilerplate)

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a bit? The github link is all well and good for supporting your answer, but you should at least try to introduce it a bit.

Comment: The README.md in the gae-boilerplate root explains it all.
https://github.com/droot/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 7):

I think the first option is considered the best practice. And make the code folder your first package. The Rietveld project developed by Guido van Rossum is a very good model to learn from. Have a look at it: http://code.google.com/p/rietveld

With regard to Django 1.0, I suggest you start using the Django trunk code instead of the GAE built in django port. Again, have a look at how it's done in Rietveld.

Comment: What is the best reason to use Django? I've been using WebApp, and it's been serving me just fine. Besides, I'm hoping Google will offer a better integration of the two sometime soon.

What's the downside to using the built in Django port?

Answer (score 3):

I like [webpy](http://webpy.org/) so I've adopted it as templating framework on Google App Engine.
My package folders are typically organized like this:

```
app.yaml
application.py
index.yaml
/app
   /config
   /controllers
   /db
   /lib
   /models
   /static
        /docs
        /images
        /javascripts
        /stylesheets
   test/
   utility/
   views/
```

[Here](http://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely up to date on the latest best practices, et cetera when it comes to code layout, but when I did my first GAE application, I used something along your second option, where the code and templates are next to eachother.

There was two reasons for this - one, it kept the code and template nearby, and secondly, I had the directory structure layout mimic that of the website - making it (for me) a bit easier too remember where everything was.