# Google App Engine Project hierarchy

Tags: django, google-app-engine, hierarchy

I'm working on a google app engine (with Django) and I just can't figure out what's a good practice for folder hierarchy.. I've looked at this: [Project structure for Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458/project-structure-for-google-app-engine)
but one thing isn't clear - what if I have static folder (like js files) that are unique to my app, not project? where do they go?
my current hierarchy is:

proj

- static

** js

** css

- myapp

** templates

So when a template inside my app sends a GET for js/script.js. this gets redirected to /myapp/js/script.js, which my server doesn't recognize.

here is my project url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 (r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

and here is my myapp.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
 (r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
)
```

how should I rearrange this to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use absolute URLs? Prefix your references to static resources with a `/`, and all will be well.