# Organize my python project for MVC patern,

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Python is new for me, and I've got problems to organize my files codes.

I want to do something like :

```
./
 /views
        index.html  // Django files

 /controlers
        main.py

 /models
        Greeting.py  // I take the same classe exemple of Google App Engine Website
 /libs
        xxx.py //some Lib and tools classes  
 /static
        /js
        /css
        /images
```

And The real problem is is that files tree is correct in python environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project structure for Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458/project-structure-for-google-app-engine)

Comment: I have created a GAE/Python framework that provides a directory structure very much like that one and does a lot of repetitive work for you. You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/gae-mvc-engine/. The extensive documentation can be found at: http://blog.adamcrossland.net/asset/show/mvc-engine-docs

Comment: @Adam Crossland  ok I sent you an email few hours ago to know if your project is still alive. Thanks

Comment: @Christophe, so you did, and I responded. I'm very much available to answer questions and provide guidance regarding implementing with MVCEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your structure works or if you find my example useful here's how I organize a smaller app engine app:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── conf.py
├── main.py
├── model.py
├── static
│   ├── 1.gif
│   ├── 2.gif
│   ├── 3.gif
│   ├── 4.gif
│   ├── anim.gif
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── main.js
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── error.html
    ├── info.html
    ├── upload.html
    ├── user.html
    └── welcome.html
```